# ACL list - SELF

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

OS - Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

What do you mean by SELF in DNS Zone Security Setting. ( Access Control List )

Please see the print-screen below for more info.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Standard SID for Principal Self or Self is **S-1-5-10**

A placeholder in an ACE on a user, group, or computer object in Active Directory. When you grant permissions to Principal Self, you grant them to the security principal represented by the object. During an access check, the operating system replaces the SID for Principal Self with the SID for the security principal represented by the object.

In Short, in DNS Security Properties, it is probably Computer Object.
For more Detail - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978401.aspx